# Losing generic type info in Arrays.asList() call

Tags: java, generics

In a unit test, I have code like this:

```
@Mock
private AbstractCacheImpl<?>    cache;

@Before
public void setup() {
    xxxx.setCacheImplementations(Arrays.asList(cache)); // error
}
```

On the "error" line, Eclipse (and command-line javac) says:

```
The method setCacheImplementations(List<AbstractCacheImpl<?>>) in the type xxxx is 
 not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>)
```

This is the method definition:

```
void setCacheImplementations(List<AbstractCacheImpl<?>> cacheImplementations) { this.cacheImplementations = cacheImplementations; }
```

I've seen similar questions, and I've tried variations of those solutions, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I tried variations of "`Arrays.<stuff>asList(...)`" but those didn't even have any effect.

I also tried even casting the entire return value of "asList()" to the expected return type, but that doesn't work either.  It simply says I can't cast that return value to that type.

Comment: I have seen similar errors result from prior errors in the same file, such as a failure to resolve the type (in your case, that would be a failure to resolve AbstractCacheImpl).

Comment: What happens if you extract the asList() into a variable ? Also, please provide version of Java since it matters (Java 8 introduced some changes to type inference).

Comment: This is the only error in the project, using Java 8. I'll experiment with putting it into a variable.

Comment: Extracting to a variable makes no difference. It still assumes it's "List<Object>", which doesn't work in the setter parameter, and casting it to "List<AbstractCacheImpl<?>>" says you can't cast to that.

Comment: Oh.  Duh. Figured it out. I ended up getting the wrong import for "Arrays".